# Deserialize JSON into a generic class with type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a list of JSON objects with the simplified structure shown here:

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "type": "int32",
    "default": 110
}
```

The "type" property could vary (int16, int32, float, etc) and the "default" property should correctly reflect the type.  Here is my generic C# class:

```
public class ConfigurationParameter<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("default")]
    public T Default { get; set; }
}
```

My goal here is to read in a list of these JSON objects deserialize them into the typed version of ConfigurationParameter based on the "type" property.  I started by creating a custom JSON converter:

```
public class ConfigurationParameterConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        if (obj["type"] != null)
        {
            if(obj["type"].ToString() == "int32")
            {
                return obj.ToObject<ConfigurationParameter<int>>();
            }
            else if (obj["type"].ToString() == "float")
            {
                return obj.ToObject<ConfigurationParameter<float>>();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But when I am actually deserializing the JSON string, I am not sure what type to request back since I won't know what the outputted strongly typed object will be?

```
//doesn't compile
var typedConfigurationParameter = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfigurationParameter<T>>(json, settings);
```

I am not quite sure if this is something I can't do because it can't be figured out at runtime?  Or if I am possibly just not approaching the solution correctly?

Comment: I figured there was some prior art, so I [did a bit of searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=typed+json) and found some.

Comment: Have you thought of simplifying the class to a non generic and simply change the type to `object` for the `Default` property just for deserialization purpose and then from the collection of `ConfigurationParameter` you get from it you can instantiate another generic class for each now that you have the type loaded

Comment: @Franck Yeah good suggestion.  I was going to do something similar, and I think you confirmed it.  Just deal with extracting the strongly typed object when I need it (and after they've been parsed and created).

Comment: @BenKrueger look in to https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm - setting it to Auto should help resolve your issue. Watch out for security in deserialization though.